# Notification Sound interrupting Music

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I am trying to play Notification Sound without disturbing other Music playing

Notification Sound can be played by 2 ways

1) Played by OS itself via NotificationBuilder

Benifits:- Handle itself all the cases of not playing sound in Phone Calls and other cases as well
Problem:-  When music is playing and notification comes, then it shifts audio focus from music to notification, there by lowering or silencing music depending on how that music player app has handled the loss in audio focus.

2) We play sound via our media Player whenever notification comes

A) Play on NOTIFICATION STREAM ---> works perfectly fine but gives probem of ducking when played via earphones

B) Play on SYSTEM STREAM

Benifits:- No shifting of audio focus, so no effect on music when notification comes

Problem:- We will have to handle other cases of not playing sound in Telephonic call and VOIP as well...and may be other not known cases as of now .

But I figured it that watsup is doing fine.

So don't know how it is doing it

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Android 5.0 behavior changes on notification sounds](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#NotificationsSoundVibration):

> If you are currently adding sounds and vibrations to your notifications by using the [Ringtone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html), [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), or [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) classes, remove this code so that the system can present notifications correctly in priority mode. Instead, use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) methods to add sounds and vibration.
>
> Setting the device to [RINGER_MODE_SILENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_SILENT) causes the device to enter the new priority mode. The device leaves priority mode if you set it to [RINGER_MODE_NORMAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) or [RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL).
>
> Previously, Android used [STREAM_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC) as the master stream to control volume on tablet devices. In Android 5.0, the master volume stream for both phone and tablet devices is now unified, and is controlled by [STREAM_RING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_RING) or [STREAM_NOTIFICATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_NOTIFICATION).

As there is not a direct way to detect whether a device is in priority mode, you should always use the `Notification.Builder`/`NotificationCompat.Builder` methods to add sound to your notifications to ensure you meet the user's expectations.

Comment: Thanks for clearing concepts on this.But for devices below 5.0 how do i do it?is there any way?Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't do anything different: `NotificationCompat.Builder` should be used for all API levels as that is the best way to provide a consistent experience across all API levels, devices, and handles all of the edge cases you rightfully point out.

Comment: But in this case, when music is playing in Google play and if notification comes from my App.OS shifts Audio Focus to our notification as it contains sound and so google play lowers its vol , then out noitification is played and then volume is back.

But this does not happens in watsup.
So how does watsup handles this?

Comment: Yes, that is how notification sounds work. Other apps that do not work that way are not and will become even more inconsistent with every built in app and the user's expectations.